# Best way to get value from column acording other column in Pentaho

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have the table with this columns:

```
id | name | idx | value_1 | value_2 | value_3 | ...
1  | red  | 2   | null    | 10      | null
2  | green| 1   | 25      | null    | null
3  | pink | 3   | null    | null    | 100
```

what is the best way to filter the information from the value_1 or value_2 or value_3 columns, but according to the idx column in Pentaho?

if idx is 2, get value from column value_2.
if idx is 1, get value from column value_1.

But my table can have a lot of columns value_n...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "Modified JavaScript value" step to accomplish that.

```
var filtered_value;
// or use a Switch Statement
if (idx == '2') {
  filtered_value = value_2;
} else if (idx == '1')
{
  filtered_value = value_1;
} else  {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: for better performance, you can use "User Define Java Class".